# Manipulate Regex to ignore the space and disallow numbers and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a working regex pattern to validate some name

> `` /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/ ``

it validates a full name

so I have to put a space in the middle of the word, means

"Ahmed Mohsen" > valid

"Ahmed" > not valid

I want to ignore the space, to make "Ahmed" valid

also, to disallow the numbers/special characters from the name

**Note**

the idea of determining characters from a to Z and so on, is a bad idea

because some users may write their names in Arabic (Arabic characters)

Comment: Not useful to the answer of your question, but what if the user goes by an mononymous name?

Comment: @RyanZhang
It's exactly my question, I want the pattern to accept the mononymous name normally

Comment: `/^(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)+(?:\s(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)+)*$/u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wiktor Stribiżew mentioned in the comment, this can be achieved using:

```
/^(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)+(?:\s(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)+)*$/u
```

Please mark a correct answer so the question can be categorized appropriately.